# Encoding SVG into URL format

Tags: url, svg

I am trying to convert dynamically generated `<svg>` into URL format, however I have some problems. When I use online tools or Sever Side library the output is like below which is incorrect as the browser will not interpret it correctly. The second example is done manually and it is correct. I've noticed that the "+" sign should be converted to %20

Incorrect:

```
%3Csvg+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Ew3%2Eorg%2F2000%2Fsvg%22+height%3D%2250%22%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

Correct:

```
%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20height%3D%2250%22%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

EDIT:
Another difference is that in the not working solution the "." dot is encoded to %2E

Can anyone enlighten me why the code generated by online tools and Server side library is not getting displayed ?

Comment: `+` is a common convention for encoding spaces in URLs; I don't know if there is a formal recognition/name for that. `%20` is the generic escaped form of a space (ASCII 32 / 0x20). Some tools will let you choose which representation you want.

Comment: However, you haven't explained where you're trying to use this URL, so it's hard to say why that use isn't working.

Comment: @IMSoP I use that url as CSS background, I just have a thought if that could be attributed that the site I work on is encoded to charset=iso-8859-1